# Backbone model validation standards (Is it wrong to do it this way?)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm working on creating a validation view using backbone that will handle the display of the validation message in a styled balloon over a given input.  I have created a new view which handles this functionality.  To perform the validation AND render the view I have setup the following function inside of my model.

```
   Dashboard.Models.EventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "Id",

    // Model Service Url
    url: function () {
        var base = 'apps/dashboard/EventsDetails';
        return (this.isNew()) ? base : base + "/" + this.id;
    },

    validate: function (attrs) {
        var validTime = (attrs.Time) ? attrs.Time.match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/) : true;

        if (!validTime) {
            new Dashboard.Views.ValidationMessageView({
                $container: $('#txtNewEventTime'),
                message: 'Invalid Time'
            }).render();

                    return 'error';
        };

    }

});
```

My question:  Is it against standards to create that new view (ValidationMessageView) and render it from within a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO: yes!.. it doesn't look very nice.

You should instantiate the `View` outside the `Model`.

You should *bind* the *event* `error` in the Model, capture it from outside and instantiate the `ErrorView` there.

Check [the example in the `Model.validate` documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate)

In a fast though you can have a `AllErrorsView` like this:

```
// code simplfied and not tested
var AllErrorsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.on( "error", this.showError, this );
  },

  showError: function( model, error ){
    if( error == "txt_new_event_time" ) {
      new Dashboard.Views.ValidationMessageView({
        el:         "#txtNewEventTime",
        message:    "Invalid Time"
      }).render();
    }

    // ... more errors
  }

});

var myAllErrorsView = new AllErrorsView({ model: myModel });
```

I have to say that is not the only weird thing I see in your code. For example I don't understand the meaning of your `Model.url` implementation, I think you can solve it with [Model.urlRoot attribute](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-urlRoot).

Comment: Thanks, yeah perhaps I need to look at urlRoot closer.  This is my first backbone app so I'm sure there are places my code could improve.